# Append textarea after double click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a logic that allows you to edit text by double-clicking. I would like to click enter to add `<br/>` tag in text, but after focus out hide the `<br>` tag and display text line under the line with no 
. This is my code:

```
var oriVal;
$("#parentUL").on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
    oriVal = $(this).text();
    $(this).text("");
    $("<textarea wrap='off' rows='1'></textarea>").appendTo(this).val(oriVal).focus();
});
$("#parentUL").on('focusout', 'li > textarea', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().text($this.val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') || oriVal);
    $this.remove(); // Don't just hide, remove the element.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wabLp/428/

Comment: Don't use `<br/>` if you are trying to maintain the newlines. Use CSS property [white-space](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Comment: don't use .text() to insert/retrieve html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property on your list items.

```js
$(function() {
  var oriVal;
  $("#parentUL").on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
    oriVal = $(this).text();
    $(this).text("");
    $("<textarea wrap='off' rows='1'></textarea>").appendTo(this).val(oriVal).focus();
  });
  $("#parentUL").on('focusout', 'li > textarea', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // good idea to trim
    var newVal = $.trim($this.val());
    $this.parent().text(newVal || oriVal);
    $this.remove(); // Don't just hide, remove the element.
  });

});
```

```css
/* you want to maintain the whitespace characters */
li {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='parentUL'>
  <li>dad</li>
  <li>ads</li>
</ul>
```

If you choose to go with the `<br />` approach, then you'll have to use `.html()` instead of `.text()`.